# Help needed renaming custom post

Tags: customization

I really have very little Wordpress knowledge and I need help with the following:

I have a theme which uses a custom post called 'services'. I needed another custom post created which worked exactly the same as services so I went through all the code and copied and pasted wherever I found references to services and changed it to "signage". This worked ok, however on the WP admin screen, "signage" is called "posts" as is the original "posts", and I cant work out how to change the name to signage. I have been able to change the original "posts" name but not the custom post.

Comment: Show us your code which creates your `signage` CPT.

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the 'name' in the labels array of the register post type. It would be much easier to help if you can show us your code.